# Change layout spacing in bootstrap 3 navigation menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got a full-width navigation menu right above my bootstrap3 `container` div (which maxes out at 1170).

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <!-- menu -->
</div>

<div class='container'>
    <!-- content -->
</div>
```

You can see the sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/xrXt2/show/. Everything is working as it's supposed to. However, I want to change the layout of the navigation menu and I have no idea how to go about this. I still want the navigation menu to stretch across the entire width, but the text inside it should be moved (once it shrinks down into the single icon button for the menu, it looks fine and it can remain as is). Ideally, when the menu options are still expanded, I'd like to change two things:

(1) The left edge of "sitename" should be aligned with the left edge of the `container`.

(2) The right edge of "help" should be aligned with the right edge of the `container`.

I'm guessing that, for those who know what they're doing in terms of modifying bootstrap's css, this is a relatively easy task. Unfortunately, I am truly lost as to where to begin.

In summary, here is how it looks now:

[image: original]

And here is how I'd like it to look:

[image: desired]

As mentioned, this is the default layout when the width shrinks to the size of the `container`, and I have no interest in changing this behaviour:

[image: shrunk]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the navbar in a .container div and add .nav-right to the .nav

Updated to reflect documentation specifying not to use .pull-* on navbars.

Here is an updated example.
http://jsfiddle.net/xrXt2/2/show/

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand navigate" href="#">sitename</a>
    </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sync</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">help</a></li>
        </ul>

        </div><!--/nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div> <!-- /static navbar -->
```

Comment: I just discovered that bootstrap describe `.pull-right` as [*Not for use in navbars*](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats).

Answer (score 1):

Morgan ARR Allen already answered but the `navbar-right` class should be used in order to align a part of the menu to the right, this class is used in an [example provided by bootstrap itself](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/). Plus the bootstrap documentation shows [a warning about using `.pull-right`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats):

> ### Not for use in navbars
>
> To align components in navbars with utility classes, use .navbar-left
>   or .navbar-right instead. See the navbar docs for details.

So the code is:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand navigate" href="#">sitename</a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sync</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">help</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div><!--/nav-collapse -->
  <div class="container">
</div> <!-- /static navbar -->
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xrXt2/5/show/)

Update: as seen is the source code, [`pull-right`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/64e81324261548a8de8cda5fde4b87d0f7a8f8fb/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L5649) and [`navbar-right`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/64e81324261548a8de8cda5fde4b87d0f7a8f8fb/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L3109) use different rules.

Update2: added quote from bootstrap documentation.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for the extra info. Could you think of a use case, related to my requirements, where they would produce different layouts? Forgive me if that's a stupid question, I'm still learning about CSS.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, Different layouts between what and what?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to get at whether or not your solution and Morgan's solution are functionally identical. If not, what scenario would highlight the difference? Additionally, I just noticed that in your solution, the background of the navbar extends to the `content` area as well.

Comment: @a.real.human.being: I updated my answer, in the new jsfiddle the background problem is fixed.

Comment: @Morgan ARR Allen: nice catch. Changing `navbar-right` to `pull-right` in the documentation example gives a better alignment!